# POST javascript variable to JSON on form submit

Tags: javascript, json, forms, input, hidden

I need to have number format passed to JSON and I cannot use input type hidden because it returns string. I have `const formDataJsonString = JSON.stringify(plainFormData);` to translate form data to JSON (see below)

How do I POST javascript variable from form into JSON with the functions that I added below?

I have written this to convert it into number but have no clue on how to submit the javascript variable to JSON.

```
<input type="hidden" class="number" name="applicationType" value=3>

$("#form").submit(function(){
    var formInfo = document.forms['form'];
    var applicationType = parseInt($(".number").val());
});
```

The desired result in JSON:

```
applicationType: 3
```

Instead of:

```
applicationType: "3"
```

UPDATE 1:
So I have this to make it into JSON, and then POST it:

```
//url is the api
async function postFormDataAsJson({ url, formData }) {
    const plainFormData = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());
    
//put all accountsToLink value into an array
plainFormData["accountsToLink"] = new Array //create array
$("input[name=accountsToLink] ").each(function() {
plainFormData["accountsToLink"].push($(this).val()) //push value in array
});

    const formDataJsonString = JSON.stringify(plainFormData);
    const fetchOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json",
        },
        body: formDataJsonString,
    };
    const response = await fetch(url, fetchOptions);
    if (!response.ok) {
        const errorMessage = await response.text();
        throw new Error(errorMessage);
    }
    else if (response.ok) {
        window.location.href = "confirmation.html";
    }
    return response.json();
}



async function handleFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const form = event.currentTarget;
    const url = form.action;
    try {
        const formData = new FormData(form);
        const responseData = await postFormDataAsJson({ url, formData });
        console.log({ responseData });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
const testform = document.getElementById('testform');
testform.addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmit);
```

Comment: With the code you show us, it is not likely the number becomes a string

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood me. Because the input type hidden gives me applicationType: "3". And I am working on the incomplete jquery to convert it into number and want to POST the variable from jquery like how a normal form would with input type hidden.

Comment: I see only the code you provide `applicationType = parseInt($(".number").val()` and with that code  you have a number  - also when you JSON.stringify it as I show in my answer

Comment: Please show the code that makes it into JSON for the API

Comment: Alright I have updated my question, please have a look.

Comment: Sorry, I updated another function there. That's all functions I got for the form POST method

Comment: `const formDataJsonString = JSON.stringify(plainFormData);` – this is where you create your JSON, so obviously you need to make sure that the value is a number in `plainFormData` already.

Comment: Yes exactly, so my question is how do I pass the variable that I converted to number to plainFormData?

Comment: Hi , you just need add that `number` inside json which you already have i.e : `plainFormData["applicationType"] =applicationType;` . Working Fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/3h5w1qgm/

Comment: Hi Swati, good to hear from you again! Your method seems clean and direct. It worked for the number, but do you know how to do the same for boolean? For example, i have this  input type="hidden" name="linkAllAccounts" value=true

Comment: Yup simply write `plainFormData["linkAllAccounts"] =(get here value of that input);`

Comment: Ya but how do I parse it into boolean at the first place? If i were to have .boolean as the class

Comment: This should work : `plainFormData["linkAllAccounts"] =$(".boolean").val() =="true" ? true : false;`

Comment: I prefer using these 2 : 
var linkAllAccounts = Boolean($("input[name=linkAllAccounts]").val()); plainFormData["accountsToLink"] =accountsToLink;     They should work as well right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225097/discussion-between-swati-and-hayden-ng).

Answer (score 1):

So you failed to mention you do NOT do what you did in the initial post but instead you use formData

You cannot use formData to JSON integers.

You can map a serialized array and stringify that

```js
async function postFormDataAsJson({ url, formData }) {
  const formDataJsonString = JSON.stringify(formData);
  console.log(url,formDataJsonString)
  // ....
}


async function handleFormSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const form = event.currentTarget;
  const url = form.action;
  try {
    const formData = $(form).serializeArray().map(
      item => ({ [item.name]: isNaN(item.value) ? item.value : +item.value})
    );
    const responseData = await postFormDataAsJson({ url, formData }); 
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

$("#testform").on("submit", handleFormSubmit);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="testform" action="/bla.php">
  <input type="hidden" class="number" name="applicationType" value=3>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, yes the function that I wrote is indeed returning number, which is what I want. But how do I submit it like how a normal form would with input type hidden. Let me know if I am not clear enough. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your response and sorry for the misinterpretation. Your method seems to work. But by the look at the json, it seems that all input type hidden that value is a number has all became number without even converting them. 

Can I ask what happens to my 'async function postFormDataAsJson({ url, formData })' ? I'm confused on setting this function to work with the serializeArray that you provided. 

Much thanks!

Comment: You chopped it. My serialisedForm replaces your formData in your second function: `const serialisedForm = $(form).serializeArray().map(item => ({[item.name]:isNaN(item.value)?item.value:+item.value})); const responseData = await postFormDataAsJson({url,serialisedForm});`

Comment: The unary plus in `+item.value` converts anything not isNaN to a number

Comment: I see. Thanks for the info. By chopped you mean removing it? Sorry because I'm a beginner to this so I am not sure what to do to modify the first function so that they fit together. Would you be kind enough to update it for me? Thanks a mil!